# Unable to solve out of memory on Amazon Sagemaker for a longformer model

Tags: python, memory-management, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, amazon-sagemaker

I keep getting a memory error in the script below. I implemented parallelism, cache clearing, mixed precision training, added an environment variable for memory management, nothing seems to change the situation. I am running an Amazon Sagemaker Studio notebook in ml.p3.8xlarge instance which has 32 cpus with 244G in CPU memory and 4 v100 GPUs with the total of 64G GPY memory (16G each) which should be enough, but I think I am only using a single GPU rather than all 4 of them, which may cause the memory issue?

The model runs on CPUs only (ml.m5.12xlarge instance) without GPUs, but pretty slowly. What else can I try? My script and the error message are below.

Script:

```
import os

# Set the environment variable
os.environ['PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF'] = 'expandable_segments:True'

### With a dropout layer and custom configuration WITHOUT early stopping --- CLEANED UP WITH BETTER GPU ACCELERATION ######

import torch
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, RandomSampler, SequentialSampler
from transformers import LongformerTokenizer, LongformerForSequenceClassification, LongformerConfig, AdamW, get_linear_schedule_with_warmup
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, confusion_matrix, f1_score
from sklearn.utils.class_weight import compute_class_weight
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from torch.cuda.amp import GradScaler, autocast

# Assuming 'transcripts_df' is defined and loaded with data
# Clean data
transcripts_df.dropna(subset=['questions_answers', 'label', 'presentation', 'label_2'], inplace=True)

### Data Preparation ###
tokenizer = LongformerTokenizer.from_pretrained('allenai/longformer-base-4096')
tokenized_data = tokenizer(transcripts_df['questions_answers'].tolist(), padding="max_length", truncation=True, max_length=2048, return_tensors="pt")

label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
encoded_labels = label_encoder.fit_transform(transcripts_df['label'])

class_weights = compute_class_weight('balanced', classes=np.unique(encoded_labels), y=encoded_labels)
class_weights_tensor = torch.tensor(class_weights, dtype=torch.float)

# Split data into training, validation, and test sets
train_val_inputs, test_inputs, train_val_labels, test_labels = train_test_split(
    tokenized_data['input_ids'], encoded_labels, test_size=0.1, random_state=42)
train_val_masks, test_masks, _, _ = train_test_split(
    tokenized_data['attention_mask'], encoded_labels, test_size=0.1, random_state=42)

train_inputs, validation_inputs, train_labels, validation_labels = train_test_split(
    train_val_inputs, train_val_labels, test_size=0.1111, random_state=42)
train_masks, validation_masks, _, _ = train_test_split(
    train_val_masks, train_val_labels, test_size=0.1111, random_state=42)

### Dataset and DataLoader Setup ###
class TranscriptsDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, input_ids, attention_masks, labels):
        self.input_ids = input_ids
        self.attention_masks = attention_masks
        self.labels = torch.tensor(labels)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return {'input_ids': self.input_ids[idx], 'attention_mask': self.attention_masks[idx], 'labels': self.labels[idx]}

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.labels)

train_dataset = TranscriptsDataset(train_inputs, train_masks, train_labels)
validation_dataset = TranscriptsDataset(validation_inputs, validation_masks, validation_labels)
test_dataset = TranscriptsDataset(test_inputs, test_masks, test_labels)

# Utilizing multiple workers in DataLoader for efficient data loading
train_dataloader = DataLoader(train_dataset, sampler=RandomSampler(train_dataset), batch_size=8, num_workers=16)
validation_dataloader = DataLoader(validation_dataset, sampler=SequentialSampler(validation_dataset), batch_size=8, num_workers=16)
test_dataloader = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=8, num_workers=4)

### Model Configuration 1 ###
custom_config = LongformerConfig.from_pretrained(
    'allenai/longformer-base-4096',
    num_labels=len(set(encoded_labels)),
    attention_probs_dropout_prob=0.1,
    hidden_dropout_prob=0.1
)


model = LongformerForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(
    'allenai/longformer-base-4096',
    config=custom_config
)

# Check if more than one GPU is available and wrap the model with DataParallel
if torch.cuda.device_count() > 1:
    print(f"Using {torch.cuda.device_count()} GPUs!")
    model = torch.nn.DataParallel(model)
    
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
model.to(device)

optimizer = AdamW(model.parameters(), lr=5e-5, weight_decay=0.01)
scheduler = get_linear_schedule_with_warmup(optimizer, num_warmup_steps=0, num_training_steps=len(train_dataloader) * 10)

### Implementing Mixed Precision Training ###
scaler = GradScaler()

### Training and Evaluation Functions ###
def train_model(model, train_dataloader, validation_dataloader, epochs=10):
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        model.train()
        total_train_loss = 0

        for batch in train_dataloader:
            batch = {k: v.to(device) for k, v in batch.items()}
            optimizer.zero_grad()

            with autocast():
                outputs = model(**batch)
                loss = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss(weight=class_weights_tensor.to(device))(outputs.logits.view(-1, model.num_labels), batch['labels'].view(-1))

            scaler.scale(loss).backward()
            scaler.step(optimizer)
            scaler.update()

            total_train_loss += loss.item()
            scheduler.step()
        
        # Clear cache after completing all batches in an epoch
        torch.cuda.empty_cache()
        
        avg_train_loss = total_train_loss / len(train_dataloader)
        print(f"Epoch {epoch + 1}, Average Training Loss: {avg_train_loss}")
        evaluate_model(model, validation_dataloader)
        

def evaluate_model(model, dataloader):
    model.eval()
    total_eval_loss = 0
    all_predictions = []
    all_true_labels = []

    for batch in dataloader:
        batch = {k: v.to(device) for k, v in batch.items()}
        with torch.no_grad():
            outputs = model(**batch)
            loss = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss(weight=class_weights_tensor.to(device))(outputs.logits.view(-1, model.num_labels), batch['labels'].view(-1))

        total_eval_loss += loss.item()
        logits = outputs.logits
        predictions = torch.argmax(logits, dim=-1).cpu().numpy()
        all_predictions.extend(predictions)
        all_true_labels.extend(batch['labels'].cpu().numpy())

    # Clerar fter evaluation loop
    torch.cuda.empty_cache()
    
    avg_val_loss = total_eval_loss / len(dataloader)
    avg_val_accuracy = accuracy_score(all_true_labels, all_predictions)
    avg_val_f1 = f1_score(all_true_labels, all_predictions, average='weighted')
    print(f"Validation Loss: {avg_val_loss}, Validation Accuracy: {avg_val_accuracy}, Validation F1 Score: {avg_val_f1}")

    # Plotting confusion matrix
    cm = confusion_matrix(all_true_labels, all_predictions)
    sns.heatmap(cm, annot=True, fmt='d', cmap='Blues', xticklabels=label_encoder.classes_, yticklabels=label_encoder.classes_)
    plt.xlabel('Predicted labels')
    plt.ylabel('True labels')
    plt.title('Confusion Matrix')
    plt.show()

### Predict Function ###
def predict(model, dataloader):
    model.eval()
    predictions = []
    with torch.no_grad():
        for batch in dataloader:
            batch = {k: v.to(model.device) for k, v in batch.items()}
            outputs = model(**batch)
            preds = torch.argmax(outputs.logits, dim=-1)
            predictions.extend(preds.cpu().numpy())
    return predictions


### Main Training Loop ###
torch.cuda.empty_cache()  # Clear memory cache before starting training
train_model(model, train_dataloader, validation_dataloader, 5)


### Save Model Checkpoint to S3 Bucket ###
def save_model_to_s3(model, s3_bucket, s3_path):
    # Save model state dict to a temporary file
    model_checkpoint_path = '/tmp/longformer_checkpoint.pth'
    torch.save(model.state_dict(), model_checkpoint_path)
    
    # Upload the model checkpoint to S3
    s3.upload_file(model_checkpoint_path, s3_bucket, s3_path)
    print(f"Model saved to S3 bucket: {s3_bucket}, Path: {s3_path}")

### Load Model Checkpoint from S3 Bucket ###
def load_model_from_s3(s3_bucket, s3_path, config):
    # Download the model checkpoint from S3 to a temporary file
    model_checkpoint_path = '/tmp/longformer_checkpoint_downloaded.pth'
    s3.download_file(s3_bucket, s3_path, model_checkpoint_path)
    
    # Load the model checkpoint
    model = LongformerForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(
        'allenai/longformer-base-4096',
        config=config
    )
    model.load_state_dict(torch.load(model_checkpoint_path))
    
    return model



# Evaluate the best model on the test dataset
test_predictions = predict(model, test_dataloader, 2)

# Evaluate the predictions on the test set
f1 = f1_score(test_labels, test_predictions, average='weighted')
print(f'F1 Score: {f1}')
cm = confusion_matrix(test_labels, test_predictions)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))
sns.heatmap(cm, annot=True, fmt='d', cmap='Blues', ax=ax, xticklabels=label_encoder.classes_, yticklabels=label_encoder.classes_)
ax.set_xlabel('Predicted Labels')
ax.set_ylabel('True Labels')
ax.set_title('Confusion Matrix')
plt.show()
```

Error Message is:

```
Some weights of LongformerForSequenceClassification were not initialized from the model checkpoint at allenai/longformer-base-4096 and are newly initialized: ['classifier.dense.bias', 'classifier.dense.weight', 'classifier.out_proj.bias', 'classifier.out_proj.weight']
You should probably TRAIN this model on a down-stream task to be able to use it for predictions and inference.
Using 4 GPUs!
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OutOfMemoryError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[16], line 104
    101     model = torch.nn.DataParallel(model)
    103 device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
--> 104 model.to(device)
    106 optimizer = AdamW(model.parameters(), lr=5e-5, weight_decay=0.01)
    107 scheduler = get_linear_schedule_with_warmup(optimizer, num_warmup_steps=0, num_training_steps=len(train_dataloader) * 10)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1152, in Module.to(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1148         return t.to(device, dtype if t.is_floating_point() or t.is_complex() else None,
   1149                     non_blocking, memory_format=convert_to_format)
   1150     return t.to(device, dtype if t.is_floating_point() or t.is_complex() else None, non_blocking)
-> 1152 return self._apply(convert)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:802, in Module._apply(self, fn, recurse)
    800 if recurse:
    801     for module in self.children():
--> 802         module._apply(fn)
    804 def compute_should_use_set_data(tensor, tensor_applied):
    805     if torch._has_compatible_shallow_copy_type(tensor, tensor_applied):
    806         # If the new tensor has compatible tensor type as the existing tensor,
    807         # the current behavior is to change the tensor in-place using `.data =`,
   (...)
    812         # global flag to let the user control whether they want the future
    813         # behavior of overwriting the existing tensor or not.

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:802, in Module._apply(self, fn, recurse)
    800 if recurse:
    801     for module in self.children():
--> 802         module._apply(fn)
    804 def compute_should_use_set_data(tensor, tensor_applied):
    805     if torch._has_compatible_shallow_copy_type(tensor, tensor_applied):
    806         # If the new tensor has compatible tensor type as the existing tensor,
    807         # the current behavior is to change the tensor in-place using `.data =`,
   (...)
    812         # global flag to let the user control whether they want the future
    813         # behavior of overwriting the existing tensor or not.

    [... skipping similar frames: Module._apply at line 802 (1 times)]

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:802, in Module._apply(self, fn, recurse)
    800 if recurse:
    801     for module in self.children():
--> 802         module._apply(fn)
    804 def compute_should_use_set_data(tensor, tensor_applied):
    805     if torch._has_compatible_shallow_copy_type(tensor, tensor_applied):
    806         # If the new tensor has compatible tensor type as the existing tensor,
    807         # the current behavior is to change the tensor in-place using `.data =`,
   (...)
    812         # global flag to let the user control whether they want the future
    813         # behavior of overwriting the existing tensor or not.

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:825, in Module._apply(self, fn, recurse)
    821 # Tensors stored in modules are graph leaves, and we don't want to
    822 # track autograd history of `param_applied`, so we have to use
    823 # `with torch.no_grad():`
    824 with torch.no_grad():
--> 825     param_applied = fn(param)
    826 should_use_set_data = compute_should_use_set_data(param, param_applied)
    827 if should_use_set_data:

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1150, in Module.to.<locals>.convert(t)
   1147 if convert_to_format is not None and t.dim() in (4, 5):
   1148     return t.to(device, dtype if t.is_floating_point() or t.is_complex() else None,
   1149                 non_blocking, memory_format=convert_to_format)
-> 1150 return t.to(device, dtype if t.is_floating_point() or t.is_complex() else None, non_blocking)

OutOfMemoryError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 148.00 MiB. GPU 0 has a total capacity of 15.77 GiB of which 13.62 MiB is free. Process 10925 has 15.76 GiB memory in use. Of the allocated memory 15.36 GiB is allocated by PyTorch, and 30.34 MiB is reserved by PyTorch but unallocated. If reserved but unallocated memory is large try setting PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF=expandable_segments:True to avoid fragmentation.
```

When I print the snapshot of memory usage after I get the error using `!nvidia-smi` I see the the following:

```
Thu Feb 15 11:58:35 2024       
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 535.129.03             Driver Version: 535.129.03   CUDA Version: 12.2     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla V100-SXM2-16GB           Off | 00000000:00:1B.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   48C    P0              53W / 300W |  16137MiB / 16384MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  Tesla V100-SXM2-16GB           Off | 00000000:00:1C.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   38C    P0              36W / 300W |      3MiB / 16384MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   2  Tesla V100-SXM2-16GB           Off | 00000000:00:1D.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   37C    P0              39W / 300W |      3MiB / 16384MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   3  Tesla V100-SXM2-16GB           Off | 00000000:00:1E.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   39C    P0              39W / 300W |      3MiB / 16384MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                                         
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                            |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                            GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                             Usage      |
|=======================================================================================|
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the device to cuda alone in `device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")` only uses the current GPU (index 0). While the code above was using `torch.nn.DataParallel`, it was not configured properly across the GPUs.

Here is a revised code with distributing the load across the available GPUs:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
import boto3
import torch
import torch.distributed as dist
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, Dataset, DistributedSampler
from transformers import LongformerTokenizer, LongformerForSequenceClassification, AdamW, get_linear_schedule_with_warmup
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, confusion_matrix, f1_score
from sklearn.utils.class_weight import compute_class_weight
from torch.cuda.amp import GradScaler, autocast
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Dataset class
class TranscriptsDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, input_ids, attention_masks, labels):
        self.input_ids = input_ids
        self.attention_masks = attention_masks
        self.labels = torch.tensor(labels)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return {'input_ids': self.input_ids[idx], 'attention_mask': self.attention_masks[idx], 'labels': self.labels[idx]}

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.labels)

# Function to read CSV data from S3
def read_csv_from_s3(bucket_name, key):
    csv_obj = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=key)
    body = csv_obj['Body']
    csv_string = body.read().decode('utf-8')
    
    df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv_string))
    return df

### Training and Evaluation Functions ###
# Training function
def train_model(model, train_dataloader, validation_dataloader, optimizer, scheduler, scaler, device, class_weights_tensor, epochs):
    # Ensure the model is in training mode
    model.train()
    
    # Define the accumulation steps
    accumulation_steps = 4
    
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        total_train_loss = 0
        model.zero_grad()  # Reset gradients tensors to zero
        
        for step, batch in enumerate(train_dataloader):
            # Move batch to the appropriate device
            batch = {k: v.to(device) for k, v in batch.items()}
            
            # Mixed precision training
            with autocast():
                outputs = model(**batch)
                loss = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss(weight=class_weights_tensor.to(device))(outputs.logits.view(-1, model.num_labels), batch['labels'].view(-1))
                loss = loss / accumulation_steps  # Normalize the loss due to accumulation
            
            # Scales loss. Calls backward() on scaled loss to create scaled gradients.
            scaler.scale(loss).backward()
            
            # Gradient accumulation step
            if (step + 1) % accumulation_steps == 0:
                # Unscales the gradients of optimizer's assigned params in-place
                scaler.unscale_(optimizer)
                
                # Clip gradients to help prevent the exploding gradient problem
                torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), 1.0)
                
                # Optimizer step
                scaler.step(optimizer)
                scaler.update()
                optimizer.zero_grad()  # Clear gradients

        # Update the learning rate after each epoch
        scheduler.step()

        # Call the evaluation function at the end of each epoch
        evaluate_model(model, validation_dataloader, device, epoch)



def evaluate_model(model, dataloader, device, epoch):
    model.eval()
    total_eval_accuracy = 0
    all_true_labels = []
    all_predictions = []

    # Iterate through batches in the dataloader
    for batch in dataloader:
        batch = {k: v.to(device) for k, v in batch.items()}
        with torch.no_grad():
            outputs = model(**batch)
        
        logits = outputs.logits
        predictions = torch.argmax(logits, dim=-1).detach().cpu().numpy()
        labels = batch['labels'].detach().cpu().numpy()

        total_eval_accuracy += (predictions == labels).sum().item()
        all_true_labels.extend(labels)
        all_predictions.extend(predictions)

    avg_val_accuracy = total_eval_accuracy / len(dataloader.dataset)
    print(f"Validation Accuracy: {avg_val_accuracy}")

    # Compute the confusion matrix
    cm = confusion_matrix(all_true_labels, all_predictions)
    sns.heatmap(cm, annot=True, fmt='d', cmap='Blues')
    plt.xlabel('Predicted labels')
    plt.ylabel('True labels')
    plt.title(f'Confusion Matrix at Epoch {epoch + 1}')
    plt.show()

# Prediction function
def predict(model, dataloader, device):
    model.eval()
    predictions = []
    true_labels = []
    for batch in dataloader:
        batch = {k: v.to(device) for k, v in batch.items()}
        with torch.no_grad():
            outputs = model(**batch)
            preds = torch.argmax(outputs.logits, dim=-1)
            predictions.extend(preds.tolist())
            true_labels.extend(labels.detach().cpu().numpy())
    return predictions, true_labels

def model_setup_and_training(epochs=2):
    device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

    # Data Preparation
    tokenizer = LongformerTokenizer.from_pretrained('allenai/longformer-base-4096')
    tokenized_data = tokenizer(transcripts_df['questions_answers'].tolist(), padding="max_length", truncation=True, max_length=2048, return_tensors="pt")
    label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
    encoded_labels = label_encoder.fit_transform(transcripts_df['label'])
    class_weights = compute_class_weight('balanced', classes=np.unique(encoded_labels), y=encoded_labels)
    class_weights_tensor = torch.tensor(class_weights, dtype=torch.float)

    # Split data into training, validation, and test sets
    train_val_inputs, test_inputs, train_val_labels, test_labels = train_test_split(tokenized_data['input_ids'], encoded_labels, test_size=0.1, random_state=42)
    train_val_masks, test_masks, _, _ = train_test_split(tokenized_data['attention_mask'], encoded_labels, test_size=0.1, random_state=42)
    train_inputs, validation_inputs, train_labels, validation_labels = train_test_split(train_val_inputs, train_val_labels, test_size=0.1111, random_state=42)
    train_masks, validation_masks, _, _ = train_test_split(train_val_masks, train_val_labels, test_size=0.1111, random_state=42)

    train_dataset = TranscriptsDataset(train_inputs, train_masks, train_labels)
    validation_dataset = TranscriptsDataset(validation_inputs, validation_masks, validation_labels)
    test_dataset = TranscriptsDataset(test_inputs, test_masks, test_labels)

    # Create dataloaders
    train_dataloader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=8, num_workers=32)
    validation_dataloader = DataLoader(validation_dataset, batch_size=8, num_workers=32)


    # Model, optimizer, scheduler, and GradScaler setup
    model = LongformerForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('allenai/longformer-base-4096', num_labels=len(np.unique(encoded_labels)))
    
    # Wrap the model with DataParallel
    if torch.cuda.device_count() > 1:
        print(f"Using {torch.cuda.device_count()} GPUs!")
        model = torch.nn.DataParallel(model)

    model.to(device)
    
    optimizer = AdamW(model.parameters(), lr=5e-5, eps=1e-8)
    total_steps = len(train_dataloader) * epochs
    scheduler = get_linear_schedule_with_warmup(optimizer, num_warmup_steps=0, num_training_steps=total_steps)
    
    scaler = GradScaler()

    ### Gradient Accumulation Setup ###
    accumulation_steps = 4  # Adjust based on your memory and batch size requirements

    # Training and evaluation
    train_model(model, train_dataloader, validation_dataloader, optimizer, scheduler, scaler, device, class_weights_tensor, epochs)
    

    test_dataloader = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=8)  # No need for DistributedSampler for test set
    test_predictions = predict(model, test_dataloader, device)
    f1 = f1_score(test_labels, test_predictions, average='weighted')
    
    # Compute and plot the confusion matrix for test predictions
    cm = confusion_matrix(test_true_labels, test_predictions)
    sns.heatmap(cm, annot=True, fmt='d', cmap='Blues', xticklabels=label_encoder.classes_, yticklabels=label_encoder.classes_)
    plt.xlabel('Predicted labels')
    plt.ylabel('True labels')
    plt.title('Confusion Matrix for Test Predictions')
    plt.show()
    
    print(f'F1 Score: {f1}')
    
    return model

### Save Model Checkpoint to S3 Bucket ###
def save_model_to_s3(model, s3_bucket, s3_path):
    # Save model state dict to a temporary file
    model_checkpoint_path = '/tmp/longformer_checkpoint.pth'
    torch.save(model.state_dict(), model_checkpoint_path)
    
    # Upload the model checkpoint to S3
    s3.upload_file(model_checkpoint_path, s3_bucket, s3_path)
    print(f"Model saved to S3 bucket: {s3_bucket}, Path: {s3_path}")
    
### Load Model Checkpoint from S3 Bucket ###
def load_model_from_s3(s3_bucket, s3_path, config):
    # Download the model checkpoint from S3 to a temporary file
    model_checkpoint_path = '/tmp/longformer_checkpoint_downloaded.pth'
    s3.download_file(s3_bucket, s3_path, model_checkpoint_path)
    
    # Load the model checkpoint
    model = LongformerForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(
        'allenai/longformer-base-4096',
        config=config
    )
    model.load_state_dict(torch.load(model_checkpoint_path))
    
    return model

# train the model 
trained_model = model_setup_and_training(2)
```